# Laravel 8 route problem, It gives an error like this

Tags: laravel

I am pretty new to Laravel, I don't know how can I fix this.
**I get this error:**

> Route [saveForm] not defined. (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\BlogLaravel\resources\views\admin\aboutus.blade.php)

**Routes(web.php):**

```
  Route::get('/role-register',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registered']);
  Route::get('/role-edit/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registeredit']);
  Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registerupdate']);
  Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registerdelete']);
  Route::get('/abouts',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AboutusController::class, 'index']);
  Route::post('/save-aboutus', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AboutusController::class, 'store'])->name('saveForm');
```

**and blade.php:**

```
<form action="{{route('saveForm')}}" method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Sub-title</label>
      <input type="text" name="subtitle" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="message-text"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your route name is correct?

Comment: ```php artisan route:list``` to check all the route.

Comment: Try running `php artisan route:clear`, maybe it has been cached before you name it